Why is there an error when I try to draw the sprite?
I created a sprite called cannon in the player.h file with the following code
void createPlayer() {
    Texture cannonTexture;
    if (!cannonTexture.loadFromFile("assets/cannon.png")) {
        cout << "Failed to load cannon.png" << '\n';
    }

    Sprite cannon;
    cannon.setTexture(cannonTexture);
    cannon.setPosition(500, 500);
}

Then I used this code in the main.cpp file to call the function and draw the sprite.
createPlayer();

while (window.isOpen()) {
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed || Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape)) {
            window.close();
        }
    }
    window.clear(Color(255, 255, 255));
    window.draw(cannon);
    window.display();
}

But I get a red squiggle under "cannon" in "window.draw(cannon);" with the error message "identifier 'cannon' is undefined"
FULL SOURCE CODE
lib.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

player.h
#pragma once

#include "lib.h"

Sprite createPlayer();

main.cpp
#include "lib.h"
#include "player.h"

int main() {
    Event event;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1280, 720), "Cannoneer", Style::Titlebar | Style::Close);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    Sprite cannon = createPlayer();

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed || Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape)) {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        window.clear(Color(255, 255, 255));
        window.draw(cannon);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}

player.cpp
#include "lib.h"
#include "player.h"

class player {
    Sprite createPlayer() {
        Texture cannonTexture;
        if (!cannonTexture.loadFromFile("assets/cannon.png")) {
            cout << "Failed to load cannon.png" << '\n';
        }

        Sprite cannon;
        cannon.setTexture(cannonTexture);
        cannon.setPosition(500, 500);
    }
};


In the code you posted canon is a local variable in createPlayer(). You cannot use it out of the function. One solution would be to return it from the function. Another would be to store it in a member (if the function is actually a method of a class).

So how would I make the variable accessible in other files? (Without declaring it in a header file, I want to keep it in the function if possible)

As I mentioned, you can return it from the function. See @john's answer.

Use variables from other function into the main function C++ and C++: Function can't access variable defined in main() function

The function Sprite createPlayer() promises to return some value but does not return anything. This exabits undefined behavior. SFML is irrelevant to your question, the tag is romoved. using namespace std; using namespace sf; is very bad habit.

Variables only exist in the scope in which they are declared, inthis case cannon only exists in the function createPlayer so using it in the calling function is not allowed.
To make this work you must return the object from the function that creates it, like this
Sprite createPlayer() {
    Texture cannonTexture;
    if (!cannonTexture.loadFromFile("assets/cannon.png")) {
        cout << "Failed to load cannon.png" << '\n';
    }

    Sprite cannon;
    cannon.setTexture(cannonTexture);
    cannon.setPosition(500, 500);
    return cannon;
}

Then you use the returned value in the calling function like this
Sprite cannon = createPlayer();

while (window.isOpen()) {
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed || Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape)) {
            window.close();
        }
    }
    window.clear(Color(255, 255, 255));
    window.draw(cannon);
    window.display();
}

Variable scope is a fundamental concept in C++ (and most other programming languages too). I'm not sure how you've got this far without learning about it. Perhaps you should be learning C++ from a better source? https://learncpp.com is a good online tutorial for C++, local scope is covered in lesson 2.5

Now something weird is happening, I'm getting a message that says my project contains build errors when I try to run it, and there aren't any errors listed in my console. If you want me to link all my code, I can, there's another file with the function declaration called player.cpp, and a header file called lib.h.

Wow. Closing my question when I don't even have my answer yet, also, none of those posts helped. https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/7szv7i/anyone_else_find_the_stack_overflow_community/

@ChristianB. Sound like you have a linking error. If so that's another question. Feel free to ask it. But again learncpp.com explains the linking process so maybe have a look there.

thanks, ill let you know if it works

@ChristianB. It will not be that case that the error is not listed anywhere, you're probably looking in the wrong place. You haven't described what your setup is so I can't advise, but linking errors are a different kind of error from compiler errors so maybe that is what has fooled you.

I read the article about the linker, and I'm still confused, i dont know how this applies to my issue. I'm just really confused because this never happened to me until I started using more than a main.cpp and a precomplied header file in my projects. But every time I try adding more files, this same thing happens and it's really frustrating.

BTW I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and my only library is SFML if that helps you

@ChristianB. 'More than one file' is definitely a clue that this is a linker error. The most likely reason for the problem (and again I'm speaking without knowing what the error actually is) is that you have two cpp files, but you are only telling your compiler/linker about one of them. You need to compile and link both cpp files, this does not happen automatically

@ChristianB. The other possibility would be that you are not telling the linker about the SFML library.

@ChristianB. Now that I know the compiler, have a look on the output tab, the error will probably be listed there. Incidentally I would forget about the error list tab, the output tab is where you should be looking for errors.

My error is as follows:

1>player.obj : error LNK2005: "class sf::Sprite __cdecl createPlayer(void)" (?createPlayer@@YA?AVSprite@sf@@XZ) already defined in main.obj
1>C:\Projects\Cannoneer\Cannoneer\Release\Cannoneer.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Done building project "Cannoneer.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

@ChristianB. OK that is a linker error, see LNK (not the one I was expecting though). Are you including one of your cpp files in another cpp file? Don't ever do that.

I'm not including any cpp files in another file, header or cpp. I am including header files in other header files, though. Could that cause an issue, or no?

Where have you defined createPlayer? Is that in a header file? learncpp sections 2.8 and 2.11 explain how to organise C++ code over multiple files.

I defined it in the player.cpp file with
Sprite createPlayer();

Including header files in header files is fine (as long as the header files are correct of course).

all the code looks like this
#include "lib.h"
#include "player.h"

class player {
 Sprite createPlayer();
};


@ChristianB. OK, I'm not really seeing what the problem is. The multiple definition error means that somehow you have managed to compile createPlayer twice and when the linker brings everything together it finds two definitions of createPlayer and complains. I think you would need to post all your code and explain the project structure for me to see what the actual mistake is. It seems you haven't made any of the common ones.

Ill edit my post and include all the source code

You can see from the error message that the linker says 'player.obj ... already defined in main.obj' So it found createPlayer in both main.cpp and player.cpp.

You have defined createPLayer in a header file.

I updated the question with all the source code, But all I'm doing in main.cpp is setting the Sprite cannon equal to the function createPlayer, like you said earlier. And in player.cpp, I define the function.

Oh, that's a definition? is there a way I can edit the function content without it being a redefinition?

Move the definition of createPlayer to player.cpp. Replace what you have in player.h with a declaration Sprite createPlayer();. Remove what you currently have in player.cpp

Another fundmental C++ concept, the difference between and the uses of declarations and definitions.

What's happening here is that the definition of createPlayer is in a header file, the header file is included in two cpp files, So of course when those cpp files are compiled two definitions are seen. Simplyfying greatly, the principal is that you put declarations in header files and definitions in cpp files. There are many exceptions to this rule, but that's good enough when you are a beginner.

now im getting an error in the player.h file saying "unresolved external symbol "class sf::Sprite_cdecl createPlayer(void)" (?createPlayer@@YA?AVSprite@sf@@XZ)"
I declared the function in player.h and defined it in player.cpp

@ChristianB. So now you've gone from multiple definitions to no definition. I can;t say what the mistake is without seeing the code. C++ is not intuitive, and that's why on this site we always recommend learning from a reputable source. Anyway if you want to post the all the code again I'll take another look.

updated the code

@ChristianB. OK now the problem is that you';ve put the createPlayer definition inside a class for some reason. createPlayer inside a class is not the same thng as createPlayer outside of a class. The main code thinks it is calling createPLayer outside of a class but your definition puts it inside a class. Just remove all references to class player.

@ChristianB. Maybe you want to have a class Player eventually, but that is not where your code is at the moment.

Now I get an error at line 19 in the main.cpp file (window.display();) "Exception thrown at 0x1475FFEC in Cannoneer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x1475FFEC."

@ChristianB. OK now that is a run time error, so your code has successfuly built (but unsuccessfully run). This is progress, but this really is time for a new question, since it's presumably some kind of SFML error. Try asking a new question, but before you do, try to put all your code back into a single file and post that. Much more likely to get an answer that way.

Alright, ill just wait until tomorrow

@ChristianB. I'm not an SFML expert but if I had to take a guess I would say that the problem is in loading the texture. Do you see that error message you put in your code? cout << "Failed to load cannon.png" << '\n';

If this isn't going to be an easy fix, don't bother telling me what to do, but I changed to Debug x86 and I get an error when trying to debug, not a runtime error, it says "error C4716: 'createPlayer': must return a value"

Also the image loads fine, the if statement returns false and nothing gets printed to the console

@ChristianB. OK well I can see that return cannon; is missing from the definition of createPlayer. It should be the last line. That's definiitely a problem.

Everything runs, but I don't see the sprite like intended, I assume that it's an SFML issue, and is beyond the scope of this thread. And I confirmed again that the texture loads fine

@ChristianB. OK, that's good. As I said, I'm not the person to ask about SFML.

Alright, thanks for helping me with my issue. It's a big change of pace from the usual toxicity I experience on this site. Again, thank you for putting up with my ignorance.

@ChristianB. since the answer is actually a proper one for your question as initially asked, you can consider to accept it. See here: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

@wohlstad it really didn't help, just sent me in a spiral for a few hours only to come up empty handed with no answer. I know how to accept answers, but that didn't help.

@ChristianB. While this code corrects one issue in your code, it's wrong because it fails to address another issue which is specific to SFML. In SFML a Sprite holds a pointer to the texture that it draws. Translated what that means is that the sprite does not keep the texture alive. When you return from createPlayer the texture is destroyed and this happens even when you correctly return the sprite from the function. That is the fundamental issue here. It's your job to make sure that both the sprite and the texture it refers to exist when you use them.

@ChristianB. Now this might seem a bit crazy, but it is how the deisgners of the SFML decided to go. In my opinion this is poor design, but I'm sure they had their reasons. Here's the official documentation on this issue, see the section 'The white square problem'.

@ChristianB. BTW the simple way to manage this situation would be to make both the sprite and the texture members of your player class. That way both are alive for as long as the player object they draw is alive.
